# Render Video From 2 Different Resolution

Tags: video, settings, render, resolution

I am making a compilation video from two cameras. The first camera captures video at 4K resolution and the second camera captures a video at 720x576 resolution. I do not want to lose any quality.

What is the best resolution that I should render the final video in Sony Vegas?

Thank you.

Comment: Does anybody have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not size restricted when it comes to the final render then you should definitely render in 4K.